# Django 1.11 - strange behavior in get_or_create

Tags: django

I see a strange behavior in `get_or_create`

I have no record with `slug='ian-osborn'`

```
>>> DjProfile.objects.get(slug='ian-osborn')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/code.py", line 91, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 380, in get
    self.model._meta.object_name
frontend.models.DoesNotExist: DjProfile matching query does not exist.
```

So I would expect `get_or_create` to istantiate a new `DjProfile` object but I get a `Key (slug)=() already exists.` error.

```
>>> DjProfile.objects.get_or_create(slug='ian-osborn')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 464, in get_or_create
    return self.get(**lookup), False
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 380, in get
    self.model._meta.object_name
frontend.models.DoesNotExist: DjProfile matching query does not exist.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "frontend_djprofile_slug_f04b026a_uniq"
DETAIL:  Key (slug)=() already exists.
```

DjProfile model is defined as follow:

```
class DjProfile(DateTimeModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, db_index=True, unique=True)
    ...

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('Dj Profile')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Dj Profiles')
        ordering = ('name', )
        unique_together = ('name', 'slug')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I'm running a similar query in a Django command

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from frontend.models import DjProfile

class Command(BaseCommand):
  ...
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you created *any* slugs successfully? It seems the object creation is not generating/saving the slug, so it tries to save an empty slug, which already exists.

Comment: Yep, the script successfully create many (thousands) of records. Then it start to randomly fail. I added model definition to the question

Comment: And is the `slug` field just saved to the database as is, or is there some automatic process to generate/alter it?

Comment: As the `name` field is required, I think you should give it as argument to the `get_or_create`.

Comment: yes @albar it was that. If you'd like to create an answer I'll flag it as the correct one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the `name` field is required, You should give it as argument to the `get_or_create`.